# How to stop inner loop and reiterate the whole loop including the inner one

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

i want to crawl a FAQ page using beautifulsoup, but got some problem when printing the data.

for example:

Q: question1111

A: answer1111

Q: question2222

A: answer2222

```
for q in question:
    print(q)
    for a in answer:
        print(a)
```

the output is like:

```
question1111
answer1111
answer2222
question2222
answer1111
answer2222
```

what i want is in this way:

```
question1111
answer1111
question2222
answer2222
```

Then i try to use break,

```
for q in question:
    print(q)
    for a in answer:
        print(a)
        break
```

the output became:

```
question1111
answer1111
question2222
answer1111
```

i tried continue and pass, still not working

Is there any way to run the inner loop once and then back to outer loop reiterating??

**ADDED BELOW**

The html looks like this:

```
<div>
  <h4 class="mod-wysiwyg__small-heading">Question1</h4>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="mod-wysiwyg__text">Answer1... paragraph1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="mod-wysiwyg__text">Answer1...paragraph2</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="mod-wysiwyg__small-heading">Question2</h4>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="mod-wysiwyg__text">Answer2</p>
</div>
    <div>
  <h4 class="mod-wysiwyg__small-heading">Question3</h4>
</div>
```

the code to crawl html:

```
if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    question = soup.find_all('h4', class_='mod-wysiwyg__small-heading')
    answer = soup.find_all('p', class_='mod-wysiwyg__text')

    for q, a in zip(question, answer):
        print("- - " + q.text[3:], file=open("output.txt",'a'))
        print("  - " + a.text, file=open("output.txt",'a'))
```

output is like this:

```
Question1
Answer1... paragraph1
Question2
Answer1...paragraph2
Question3
Answer2
```

Comment: missing quote in end of `"mod-wysiwyg__text>`

Comment: updated, ok now

Comment: have you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over every question and, then, loop over the next siblings to collect paragraphs of an answer until we reach a new question (because we don't want to collect answers for the next question):

```
result = []

for question in soup.select("h4.mod-wysiwyg__small-heading"):
    paragraphs = []
    for sibling in question.parent.find_next_siblings("div"):
        if sibling.h4:  # new question, exit
            break

        answer = sibling.find('p', class_='mod-wysiwyg__text')
        if answer:
            paragraphs.append(answer.text)

    result.append((question.text, " ".join(paragraphs)))
```

Output for your sample HTML:

```
[(u'Question1', u'Answer1... paragraph1 Answer1...paragraph2'),
 (u'Question2', u'Answer2'),
 (u'Question3', '')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 
what if it is not 1 to 1? because sometimes the answer break into several paragraphs..

Comment: @icantcode well, I suspect this is the problem of properly extracting questions and  answers in appropriate containers. Could you edit your question and add the other part of the code where you extract questions and answers from a page? Thanks.

Comment: @icantcode got it, could you add another question with answers there as well? Just wanna see how it looks when there are multiple questions. Thanks

Comment: @icantcode okay, updated the answer accordingly, hope that works for you.

Comment: thanks... but now i got an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @icantcode okay, your actual HTML is probably a bit different from what was shown. Updated the answer with an extra check, try it.

Answer (score 0):

if every answer and qestions not wrapped in block `div`, walk to the `.parent` and `.find_next_sibling()`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
question = soup.find_all('h4', class_='mod-wysiwyg__small-heading')

for q in question:
  firstAnswer = q.parent.find_next_sibling('div').find('p') 
  # or
  # .find('p', class_="mod-wysiwyg__text")
  print(q.text)
  print(firstAnswer.text)
```